# How to form a pivot table on two categorical columns and count for each index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of 62 undergrads from a state university with 13 column (age, class, major, GPA, etc.)

```py
print(studentSurvey)

ID    Gender    Age    Major ... Text Messages
1     F         20     Other     120
2     M         22     CS        50
.
.
.
62    F         21     Retail    200
```

I want to make pivot tables on `studentSurvey`. For example, I want to find out how many women took CS as major, men taking Others, etc. The closest I could code this out was through this:

```
studentSurvey.pivot_table(index="Gender", columns="Major", aggfunc='count')

              Age                         ... Text Messages                              
Major  Accounting  CIS Economics/Finance  ...         Other Retailing/Marketing Undecided
Gender                                    ...                                            
Female        3.0  3.0               7.0  ...           3.0                 9.0       NaN
Male          4.0  1.0               4.0  ...           4.0                 5.0       3.0
```

That is not what I require. I only require `Gender` to be the index (row) with all the unique values under `Major` to be the columns and each cell containing the count of that gender and major. I've also tried slicing only these two columns and pivoting but the results are mixed up. Can anyone suggest something better? I'm new to advanced reshaping in pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df['Gender'], df['Major'])
```

Fix your code

```
studentSurvey.pivot_table(index="Gender", columns="Major", values="ID", aggfunc="count")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(studentSurvey.groupby(['Gender','Major'])
     .value_counts()
     .unstack('Major', fill_value=0)
)
```

Or you can do `crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(studentSurvey['Gender'], studentSurvey['Major'])
```